# Installing a graphical interface on Centos VPS

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, gnome

I have a Centos 7 VPS running, with 2 CPU's and 4gb RAM.

My question is: can I install any graphical user interface on this VPS, to access it remotely, and use a web browser on it? All I need is to be able to use Google Chrome or another browser like Firefox.

If it's possible... could someone point me in the right direction? What are the steps to do it?

My Centos release is:

CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

centos-release-7-9.2009.1.el7.centos.x86_64

Thank you!

Comment: VNC is a common choice for this. There are many implementations.

Comment: in fact its possible mayve you look for xrdp but vpn or proxy might be more that what you want